# Text is centered in jQuery on lines following the first one only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a quiz, and on the quiz page, if the user clicks the Begin button, then the jQuery animation takes place, and on the animation, some text is displayed.

The problem is that the text on the first line is only centered while the animation is taking place as long as the text can fill the width of the animation. But if the text is long enough, after it goes onto the second line, it centers itself.

How can I fix my code so that even if the text is small enough to fit on only one line, it will always be centered?

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower'     rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="50.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                var div = $("#tgemp");
                startAnimation();
                function startAnimation(){
                div.animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}, 3000, "swing");
                div.css("background-color", "#99FF66");
        }
        document.getElementById("tt").style.opacity = "1";
        });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <div id = "tgemp">
        <p id = "tt"> A walk on the beach may lead to contact with sand</p>
    </div>
    <body>
        <h1>50 States Quiz</h1>
        <div id="firstDiv" align="center"> 
            <h2> Can you name all 50 states? </h2>
            <p id = "timer"> 5:00 </p>
            <button type="button" id = "time" onclick="Begin();"> Begin </button><br/><br/><br/><br/>

            <input type="text"  id = "tb" onInput="Verify()" enabled></input><br/><br/><br/>
        </div><br/>
    </body>
    <center><img src="us.png" height = '50%' id = "img"></center>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body{
background-color: #ADD8E6;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
}

h1,h2,#timer{
font-family: 'Indie Flower',serif;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 325%;
}

h2,#timer{
font-size: 200%;
}

#time {
background: #65a9d7;
border: solid 0px #1e90ff;
border-radius: 50px; 
-moz-border-radius: 50px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50px; 
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 130%;
font-family: 'Indie Flower',serif;
padding: 5px 15px;
}

#time:hover {
background: #c42f2f;
}

#time:active {
background: #FF9200;

border: solid 0px #1e90ff;
border-radius: 50px; 
-moz-border-radius: 50px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
}

#time:focus{
outline:0 !important;
}

#tb {
background-color: #ADD8E6;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,90,90,1),rgba(114,188,212,1));
border:3px solid #FF9200;
border-radius:10px;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Indie Flower',serif;
color: white;
font-size: 125%;
outline:0 !important;
}

#tgemp{
font-family: 'Indie Flower',serif;
color: #99FF66;
width:0px;
height:0px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
background-color:red;

}

#tt{
font-family: 'Indie Flower',serif;
color: white;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
font-size: 400%;
text-align: center;
}

#tt:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `width: 100%` to the #tt element, and you should be good to go! See the following jsbin for the result: http://jsbin.com/sezadoxura/1/edit?html,css,js,output